# ActionController::RoutingError rails_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/rails_validations.js"):
[image]

Comment: can you show the code? 
this file is getting called in the view. Otherwise you can require this file to your application.js and remove the code from the view, from where you're calling it

Comment: but which file code i see you ? I have use gem for validation